# Rich internet applications

Tags: rich-internet-application

I want to create a web application, where I want to enable the user to create screen mockups with rectangles and circles and enable them to move objects around.

I have to support IE and other old version of browsers where HTML5 is not enabled.

Which is best platform for that other than Flash ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go with HTML/CSS/JavaScript, [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) (JavaScript framework) provides a solid cross-browser compatible base.  It provides a drawing API ([dojox.gfx](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/gfx)) that will use whatever the browser support natively to draw shapes (HTML5 canvas in new browsers, SVG, VML for older IE browsers, etc).

Comment: Dojo looks really nice, and dojox.gfx is also neat! I'm learning Adobe Flex 4.5 now, and I've found it to be nice for development (and I'm not even using Flex Builder!) so I wouldn't count Flash out completely.